# How to change/remove the test mode and enable live mode in stripe using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, stripe-payments

Below is the code for the stripe form I am using to get the payment. But While the form is loading it is showing the test mode in right top side. I am unable to figure out how to change it to live mode now.I dont see any option on stripe dashboard as well.

```
<form id="payment-form" action="/processPayment/{{stripe}}/{{priceIDtoDisplay}}" method="POST" >
      <script
         src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
         class="stripe-button"
         data-key="{{key}}"
         data-amount="{{priceID}}"
         data-currency="usd"
         data-name="{{planName}}"
         data-description="${{priceIDtoDisplay}}/mo"
         data-locale="auto" >
       </script>
   </form>
```

Below is the attached image for the payment page for stripe when checkout for payment:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your activated your Stripe account? If so, go under `API Keys`. You should be able to toggle test mode on/off. Make sure you use live mode key if you do not want to see the "Test mode" banner.

Comment: Can you please tell me, what changes I have to convert to live mode from test mode.
1) activate to live mode in stripe dashboard
2) add live keys in code
3) changing the URL? 
and what else I need to do